# Temporarily grant permissions in ABP framework

Tags: abp

I have a site running the [ABP.io](https://abp.io/) framework where I would like to let visitors register themselves as new tenants. The problem is that creating a tenant with `ITenantAppService` requires permissions that anonymous users do not have.

Is there any way to temporarily execute code that require elevated permissions without logging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temporary disabling permissions is not a good practice. you need to create a new AppService for this purpose: `IPublicTenantAppService` and there shouldn't be permission on this service. If you have specific business logic create a new domain service and call that service in the `PublicTenantAppService`

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks for your input!

Comment: @alper-ebicoglu can you please provide a sample

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that is not perfect but working at least.

I have added a new [`PermissionValueProvider`](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization#permission-value-providers) where I check stack-trace of the current request to check if it comes from the registration page:

```
var callOriginatesFromTenantRegistrationPage = Environment.StackTrace.IndexOf("Web.Pages.Registration", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0;
```

If it is and the checked permission is `AbpTenantManagement.Tenants.Create` I set the request to Granted.

Not setting this as the answer since I hope there is a better solution out there.